# Where do I add i18n setup code in Rails 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, internationalization

I'm trying to upgrade to i18n gem version 1.12.0 and in its [README.md](https://github.com/fnando/i18n/blob/main/README.md) we are instructed to:

```
Usage
Setting up

First, you need to instantiate I18n with the translations' object, the main class of this library.

import { I18n } from "i18n-js";
import translations from "./translations.json";
const i18n = new I18n(translations);
```

I'm new to ES6. I have deduced through experimentation that this is supposed to run on the server and its output should end up in the javascript sent to the browser.  I believe it should be run via node on the server and the results somehow end up in the asset pipeline, right?

Where does the above code need to be placed in the Rails 7.0.4 system for that to happen?

I have been running i18n gem for years and am trying to upgrade to the newest version.  Documentation of the i18n gem seems to assume an advanced level of Rails knowledge and new features.

Comment: The repo you have linked to is the standalone JS version. You want https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js

Comment: "the i18n gem seems to assume an advanced level of Rails knowledge" yeah - exporting your Rails localization into a completely different language is not trivial task or something thats commonly done.

Comment: I've got i18n-js all setup and working, it produces .json file from .yml files. The prior version somehow auto generated i18n and added it to the asset pipeline on the fly.  The new version does not do that.  I do not understand why the plugin author would tell us to add code but not tell us where, like all of the ruby on rails documentation does.  I've been working with rails for 10 years but I'm still not a mind reader.

Comment: upgrade to `i18n v1.12.0`? the ruby i18n? you linked to `i18n-js` npm package currently at `v4`. readme for `i18n-js` gem, also at v4, seem to have instructions with filenames and everything, and also a migration guide: https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js/blob/main/MIGRATING_FROM_V3_TO_V4.md. and `app/javascript/application.js` would be the place to start. sure hope you're not running importmaps.

Comment: One fatal flaw of Stack Overflow is the preponderance of people who wrongly criticize the question being asked, or even worse they question if the question should even be asked in the first place.  Stack Overflow should institute a policy of "If you cannot provide the answer to the question, move on to the next question."

Comment: As I already stated, I have i18n-js setup and working.  One of the steps in setting up v4.x of i18n-js is:

Integrating with your frontend

You're done exporting files, now what? Well, go to [i18n](https://github.com/fnando/i18n) to discover how to use the NPM package that loads all the exported translation.

So max and Alex, thanks? for your efforts, but I asked the correct question for the point I am at now.

Comment: i was just asking. if we were criticizing, your question would be downvoted and closed. the reason i linked the migration guide is that it has a section: [Using your translations](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js/blob/main/MIGRATING_FROM_V3_TO_V4.md#using-your-translations) that tells you exactly the answer to what to do next with the javascript part. they're using `application.ts`, i told you `application.js` will do. unless you're using importmaps, because you wouldn't be able to import `json` directly. also *"It doesn't rely on specific parts from Sprockets"*.

Comment: I don't understand.  Adding the typescript to application.js gives an error and putting it in application.ts seems to do nothing.  It looks like the .ts files are not being run at all.